WebView plugin: catch background http requests
I've to integrate a reset password feature implemented in an existing website on my app. Once the user input the username and then hit the "Reset" button a background web request is performed and then a popup showed.
This can't be catch with onNavigationRequest and I need a way to be able to catch this background request that is normally visible for example with the developers tool on every common browser.
Is there any way to catch background website http requests using WebViewWidget controller?
